# Which way would you suggest to return default value that is not null?

Tags: c#, null, default-value

I use C# language, but I think this question is not limited with language.
I have the next function and method to return image name:

```
public Func<string> GetImageNameFunc { get; set; }

private string getImageName()
{
    if (GetImageNameFunc != null)
    {
        string imageName = GetImageNameFunc();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName))
        {
            return imageName;
        }
    }
    return "default.png";
}
```

In the past the logic was next:

- use GetImageNameFunc function to override image name
- return null or empty string to specify, that you need to use default image

Now I'd like to give one more possibility to user: he must be able to specify, that he wouldn't like to have image at all. So, he must be able to return some value from function, which would mean, that he doesn't wish to get image at all: let's say, Image.None.

I guess I can use some constant like

```
public const string NoImageName = "|";
```

, which would have a value that is inconsistent for image, and specify this constant in event comments. But I don't really like that way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Returning a defined string (ie `|`) means that the consumer of this functionality must be able to understand what that means and do something with it when it sees it.  Since that's the case, I'd just stick to returning `null` and handle the default image inside that consumer.  By consumer, it could be another method within the same class.

Comment: Why not simply add a `bool` parameter asking if he wants to backout to a default value if no image exists?

Answer (score 3):

Split the method into two cases:

```
string TryGetImageName()
{
    if (GetImageNameFunc != null)
    {
        string imageName = GetImageNameFunc();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageName))
        {
            return imageName;
        }
    }
    return null; //no default!
}

string GetImageNameOrDefault() {
 return TryGetImageName() ?? "default.png";
}
```

Your method was doing two things at once.

Alternative:

```
string TryGetImageName(string @default = "default.png") {
 //...
 return @default;
}
```

---

`NoImageName = "|"` that is not a good idea. It is a confusing hack. Rather than using magic strings create a class that holds a string and a boolean informing the caller whether the default was used or not.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was trying to get at with my comment on the OP :)

Comment: Ok, but like this, how does user specify that he wants no image at all? If he returns null, it'll still be "default.png".

Comment: The user simply calls TryGetImageName() and gets null. Or, he can call TryGetImageName(@default: null).

Comment: Or you could have the method you pass to `GetImageNameFunc` return `null` and remove the `string.isnullorempty` check

Comment: Yes, but the only public thing here is `GetImageNameFunc`, and internal entry point is `private string getImageName()`. `getImageName` is called internally, and `GetImageNameFunc` is used to specify image name by outer classes.

Comment: @ArtemKachanovskyi feel free to make public whatever needs to be visible to outside callers. Or, create public wrappers. What's the problem preventing you from doing that?

Comment: The problem is that there is some code already which uses that `GetImageNameFunc` delegate, and I can't change it's type. I guess I could add 1 more event to ask user if he wishes no image at all, and call it in `getImageName` method. I just ask about elegant way to do that :)

Comment: Can't you just say that GetImageNameFunc must return null in case no default image is wanted? Or, it must return an empty string which I guess would be a tiny bit better than a bar character.